# Continue a canceled task

Tags: c#, xamarin

Inside my code i'm using Sqlserver async. 
If i will request CancellationTokenSource in my query i can't re use it in same Activity.
Example

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts; //Global 

 cts = new CancellationTokenSource();//OnCreate Method
```

BtnClik1

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
 {
    await connection.OpenAsync(cts.Token);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cts.Token);
 }
```

BtnClick2

```
  if (cts.Token != null)
            cts.Cancel();
```

If i will press for some reson BtnClick2, then i cant re use BtnClick1, I'm taking error System Threadin tasks exception, A task was canceled

Comment: After calling `Cancel` you will have to create a new instance and assign it to `cts` using `cts = new CancellationTokenSource();`

Comment: Thank you ok, now i will understand my problem. Should i also dispose cts before creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, you should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts; 
private object syncObj = new Object();

public void BtnClik1(...)
{
   lock(syncObj)
   {
      _cts = _cts ?? new CancellationTokenSource();
   } 

   ...
}

public void BtnClik2(...)
{
   lock(syncObj)
   {
       cts?.Cancel();
       cts?.Dispose();
       cts = null; 
   } 
}
```

***Note*** : the locking isn't really needed as there is probably bigger thread safety issues.

Comment: What do i need to set it null? Dispose isn't the same?

Comment: One last question, doest Finish my activity disposes my CancellationTokenSource? Or i need to dispose it every time i close my activity?

Comment: @ddd it only needs to be disposed if it's been canceled. However if you form/activity what ever creates the cs  goes out of scope you should dispose it